# jQuery Validation syntax error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i found a script online and i edited to suit my textfields, but in my code editor it highlight the last but one line a syntax error. since i'm new to jquery code i'm having difficulty resolving it

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form_reigs').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,

            },

            lastname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },

            email2: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

            password2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },

            password23: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },

        messages :{
        "firstname" : {
         required : 'Please enter your firstname',

         "lastname" : {
         required : 'Please enter your lastname',

          "password2" : {
         required : 'Please enter your password',



         "password23" : {
         required : 'Please re-type your password',
                        }
          }

        });
        });
```

any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing brackets in your `messages`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form_reigs').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,

            },

            lastname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },

            email2: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

            password2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },

            password23: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },

        messages: {
            "firstname": {
                required: 'Please enter your firstname',
            },
                "lastname": {
                required: 'Please enter your lastname',
            },
                "password2": {
                required: 'Please enter your password',
            },
                "password23": {
                required: 'Please re-type your password',
            }
        }

    });
});
```